# MariaDB 5.5 how to count repeat value in a json?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

As title , have a data as follow:

```
|ID|jsoncolumn|
|01|{'01':'pass','01':'pass','02':'pass','03':'pass','03':'pass','03':'pass'} |
```

Any one know how to count duplicate value such as ID 01 have 2 counts ID 03 have 3 counts

Comment: JSON is not the place to store stuff for which you want to do queries like that.

Answer (score 0):

The following script can give you some ideas. Evaluate performance issues, among others, due to the number of rows your table can have. Modify and adjust everything that is necessary in the script:

```sql
MariaDB[_]> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl` (
         ->   `id` SERIAL,
         ->   `jsoncolumn` BLOB
         -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_tbl` (
         ->   `id` BIGINT,
         ->   `value` VARCHAR(255)
         -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> INSERT INTO `tbl`
         ->   (`jsoncolumn`)
         -> VALUES
         ->   ("{'01':'pass','01':'pass','02':'pass','03':'pass','03':'pass','03':'pass'}");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> SELECT
         ->   CONCAT('(', `id`, ', "',
         ->     REPLACE(
         ->         REPLACE(
         ->           REPLACE(`jsoncolumn`, '}', ''),
         ->         '{', ''),
         ->         ',', CONCAT('"), (', `id`, ', "')
         ->     ), '")'
         ->   ) INTO @`_value`
         -> FROM  `tbl`
         -> WHERE `id` = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> SET @`insert` := CONCAT('
         '>   INSERT INTO `tmp_tbl` (`id`, `value`)
         '>   VALUES ', @`_value`);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> SELECT @`insert`;
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @`insert`                                                                                                                     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| INSERT INTO `tmp_tbl` (`id`, `value`)
  VALUES (1, "'01':'pass'"), (1, "'01':'pass'"), (1, "'02':'pass'"), (1, "'03':'pass'"), (1, "'03':'pass'"), (1, "'03':'pass'") |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`insert`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Statement prepared

MariaDB[_]> EXECUTE `stmt`;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB[_]> DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> SELECT `id`, `value`, COUNT(`id`) `COUNT`
         -> FROM `tmp_tbl`
         -> GROUP BY `id`, `value`, LEFT(`value`, LOCATE(':', `value`) - 1)
         -> ORDER BY `value`;
+------+-------------+-------+
| id   | value       | COUNT |
+------+-------------+-------+
|    1 | '01':'pass' |     2 |
|    1 | '02':'pass' |     1 |
|    1 | '03':'pass' |     3 |
+------+-------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `tmp_tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB[_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

See [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=3980d44f55f3c348fd892fe00e8dad54).